# Python Directory Reader Tkinter GUI not working properly

Tags: python, user-interface, csv, tkinter

Hi Everyone I am working on my final project and I am creating a directory snooper

So here is the bottomline of this script:

1. GUI with Tkinter that asks user for directory and prompts user to
   save a cvs file to the space of their choosing. CSV will contain
   filename,file extension and file size taken from the directory that
   the user inputed.
2. My GUI has a text scroll box that should print the process of the
   script and print when it is done,

My problems:

- When saving CSV. It does not produce a CSV and I get this error
  "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".asksaveasfilename() is
  not    working
- GUI text scroll box is not working and printing out the information
     i need

  - How do I add headers to my CSV so that my CSV will have
    filename,extension,size, and comment

Attached below is my script. Can anyone help me with this?

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from array import *
import os

version = '1.0'

import os
import csv
from Tkinter import BOTH, LEFT, TOP, END, StringVar
from ttk import Frame, Entry, Button, Label
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText
from tkFileDialog import askdirectory
from tkFileDialog import asksaveasfilename


class FileWalkerWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        self.master.title("Directory Snooper v" + version)
        self.master.iconname("Directory Snooper")

        self.dir = StringVar()  # tkinter does not work with standard python variables
        self.dir.set(os.getcwd())  # set to current working directory

        description = "This program walks through a directories " \
                      + "print out name of directory file path. " \
                      + "prints out mumber of files in your in your directory. " \
                      + "It list files and tests for corrupted zipfiles and " \
                      + "creates a CSV file of the findings"

        row1 = Frame(self)
        Label(row1, text="Choose Directory:").pack(side=LEFT, pady=10)
        self.dir_ent = Entry(row1, width=80, textvariable=self.dir)
        self.dir_ent.pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(row1, text="Browse", width=10, command=self.browse).pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
        row1.pack(side=TOP, ipadx=15)

        row2 = Frame(self)
        btn = Button(row2, text="Snoop", command=self.savefile, width=15)
        btn.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=10)
        row2.pack(side=TOP)

        self.output = ScrolledText(self, height=15, state="normal",
                                   padx=10, pady=10,
                                   wrap='word')
        self.output.insert(END, description)
        self.output.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.bind('<Key-Return>', self.savefile)  # bind enter press to walk

    def browse(self):
        dirpath = askdirectory(parent=self, title="Select Directory")
        self.dir.set(dirpath)

    def savefile (self):
        self.output.delete(1.0, END)
        name=asksaveasfilename()
        with open(name,'w') as csvfile:
            dirList = os.listdir(self.dir.get())
            data = ((fname, str(os.path.getsize(self.dir.get() + "/" + fname)), str(os.path.splitext(fname)[1]),) for
                    fname in
                    dirList)
            for entry in data:
                create=csv.writer(csvfile)
                create.writerow(','.join(entry) + '\n')
                csvfile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FileWalkerWindow().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When saving CSV. It does not produce a CSV and I get this error
>   "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

You *do* close the file in your for loop:

```
for entry in data:
    create=csv.writer(csvfile)
    create.writerow(','.join(entry) + '\n')
    csvfile.close()
```

Unindent it to close the file after the for loop. You should move the `csv.writer()` outside of the `for` loop as well (as mentioned in comments):

```
create=csv.writer(csvfile)
for entry in data:
    create.writerow(','.join(entry) + '\n')
csvfile.close()
```

> GUI text scroll box is not working and printing out the information i need

The question is when you want to display the information!
You can add a button to print the content of the chosen directory or print it automatically when the user selects a folder to browse.

To do the latter, you can edit you `browse` method, which should look like:

```
def browse(self):
    dirpath = askdirectory(parent=self, title="Select Directory")
    self.dir.set(dirpath)
    self.output.insert(END, "\n" + "\n".join(os.listdir(dirpath)))
```

> How do I add headers to my CSV so that my CSV will have
>   filename,extension,size, and comment

Just write a Python string containing your headers before writing actual values:

```
with open(name,'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write("filename,extension,size,comment")
    dirList = os.listdir(self.dir.get())
    # some other stuff after...
```

---

Please note also that, while it is strongly discouraged by Python guidelines to use `from module import *` in general, the standard way to import `Tkinter` is `from Tkinter import *` :)

Comment: is that suggestion about `close` correct? It's creating a new `csv.writer` on every iteration. It seems like that needs to be moved outside the loop,too. ie: either open and close it each time, or open it before the loop and close it after.

Comment: You're right, the creation of `cvs.writer()` on every iteration is a bad thing, I'll update my answer to solve that as well. However, I addressed only the original problem which came from `csvfile.close()` being inside the loop :)